# How fill face between irregular curves?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Hello Blender Stack Exchange,

I am trying to fill a face between 4 surfaces. Two are straight edges and two are a curved line made up of short vertices that came from a SketchUp export.

The problem: I select the vertices on the top and bottom and fill the hole. It creates a strange face that ruins the curve. I would prefer it create some sort of complex curve. I want it to be smooth.

Images attached to better explain.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To deal with curves like that you need to use the **[Bridge Edge Loops](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Edges#Bridge_Edge_Loops)** tool.

If you use the fill tool (<kbd>F</kbd>) blender creates a very ugly Ngon on connecting all of the vertices like this:
[image]

Using bridge edge loop tool will give you the proper curve:
[image]

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you very much.

http://i.imgur.com/nrShTA7.jpg

Now if I can just figure out a way to smooth out the curve near the inner part...

Comment: @Peter You can ask that as a new question.