# Mesh artifacts only on render

Tags: rendering, mesh, artifacts

I am making my phone in Blender and my mesh has weird artifacts on rounded corners only on render, not in viewport. Removing doubles and flipping normals doesn't help. I thought it's releated to non-quads on rounded surface but connecting verticles with knife tool also doesn't help.

What is this and how to resolve my problem? 
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm learning myself but try bridging the edge loops on that particular face.. similar to this... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18177/how-fill-face-between-irregular-curves

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but unfortunately bridge looping made artifacts a little bit less visible but that's all.

Comment: The mesh is too high-poly to model correctly. You should be using a subsurf modifier to make things detailed (smooth, high-poly) and keeping the topology much simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a big and ugly n-gon (a polygon of more than 4 vertices) trying to bend as that curve.
[image]

You need to subdivide it into more faces.
Here's what you get when you delete that n-gon and do grid fill:

[image]

The curvature is better but far from ideal (plus you get terrible topology).

Try to create a curve that has the same number of vertices for both sides (and try to keep the rest of the topology as quads)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got it to look "right" without much work by triangulating those trouble faces, smooth-shading the object, and setting up auto-smooth.

Here is what the topology and render look like (click on it to view it full size in your browser...it's plenty high res):

[image]

And here is the blend:

[image]